# Problem with autorun: "F:\ is not a valid Win32 application"

Tags: autorun

I'm having problems with my `autorun.inf`:

```
[autorun]
open=setup.msi
```

It is placed in the root of my CD, along with `setup.msi`. When I insert the CD, or open it from explorer, I get the message:

```
F:\ is not a valid Win32 application
```

`F:` is my CD drive. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does setup.msi work otherwise (i.e. if you double-click on it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you're calling an .msi file and not an executable, perhaps you could try using `shellexecute`? Something like this:

```
[autorun]
shellexecute=setup.msi
```

Comment: What's the difference between the two?

Comment: An .msi file is not a file which can be executed by the OS. Instead it needs to be interpreted through the Windows Installer, which is associated with .msi files. "shellexecute" tells the OS to use the file's associated application rather than try to launch the file itself.